# ext4 partition from remote computer shared on network not mounting on linux via fstab

Tags: nfs, ext4, automounting, cifs

The first one works the second mount doesn't. The first mount disk D is ntfs attached via USB on a windows computer and H is attached via USB2 on same windows computer .

**/etc/fstab**

```
//192.168.5.167/D /mnt/cifs cifs credentials=/root/.smbreds,_netdev,nofail,x-systemd.automount 0 0
//192.168.5.167/ssd_ext4 /mnt/ssd  cifs credentials=/root/.smbreds,_netdev,nofail,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

also tried this

```
//192.168.5.167/ssd_ext4 /mnt/ssd nfs credentials=/root/.smbreds auto,_netdev,noatime,nolock,nofail,bg,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

but didnt work either

Comment: Is windows share really named "ssd_ext4"?

Comment: Yes, still its not loading

Comment: Could you make a test with smbclient or another Windows client? Are permission ok? Also try to mount via command line "mount -t cifs -o username=your_user //192.168.5.167/ssd_ext4 /mnt/ssd"